# Accessing Maven proxy settings in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

The `frontend-maven-plugin` passes [configured proxy settings](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#proxy-settings) through as `--http-proxy` / `--https-proxy` command line arguments with the relevant password obfuscation in log output.

Is it possible to replicate this behavior elsewhere to manually specify a command line argument e.g. also setting the http_proxy / https_proxy [environment variables](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#environment-variables) to work around an issue with a node library which [reads proxy settings from the environment](https://github.com/rxaviers/cldr-data-npm/issues/39)?

This would look something like

```xml
    <environmentVariables>
        <http_proxy>${build.proxy.uri}</http_proxy>
    </environmentVariables>
```